# Incomplete type error when trying to build a templated class that returns size of std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, type-traits

I'm trying to build a templated class that can detect whether its template parameter is of type `double` or `std::array<double, n>` and in the later case return me the value of `n`.

What I have so far is the following:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class H>
struct helper;

template<typename T, int n>
struct helper<std::array<T, n> >{
    static constexpr int len = n;
};

template<typename T>
class A{
    public:
    void test(){
        if constexpr(std::is_same<T, double>::value){
            std::cout << "T is double" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "T is array of length " << helper<T>::len << std::endl; 
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    A<std::array<double, 7> > a;
    a.test();
}
```

When I run this code I get the error

```
main.cpp:29:50: error: incomplete type ‘helper >’ used in nested name specifier
   29 |             std::cout << "T is array of length " << helper<T>::len << std::endl;
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What am I getting wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: in the application I'm trying to get this to work it is known to me that the only types that will be passed to my class are going to be either `double` or `std::array<double, n>`.

Comment: clang and MSVC both accept this code, only GCC seems to reject it

Comment: It has something to do with `int n` having the wrong type. `std::array` uses `std::size_t` for length, and `std::size_t n` makes your code work on all compilers.

Comment: The problem really was the `int`. Using `std::size_t` got it working. Thanks for the comment @HolyBlackCat